# Linux RPC delete registration

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, rpc

there is a well-worked program (daemon) running on CentOS-5.4 that makes by itself RPC registration as program 191299 version 10.

After an unplanned program stop, the RPC registration is still remaining, so the program can't get restarted due to unregister try causes the error:

```
# rpcinfo -d 191299 10    
rpcinfo: Could not delete registration for prog 191299 version 10
```

`service portmap restart` din't help too despite on successful restart.

Could you please advise - how to force the RPC registration removal?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use **service portmap restart**. It stored the current state of portmap before stopping it and restores it after start. Better do **stop** and **start**. Or

```
# service portmap stop
# rm -f /var/run/portmap.state
# service portmap start
```

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 6, rpcbind (in its default mode) allows creating a mapping from anyone over localhost, but only allows deleting the mapping if you own it or are root. If the binding is created over UDP or TCP, then rpcbind is unable to authenticate the user that is making the modification/deletion request, so it is being denied.

Calling `rpcinfo -d` as root should delete the mapping. On CentOS 6, the RPC mappings are also cleared during a system reboot (at least with our installation).

If the port is bound using UNIX sockets (`/var/run/rpcbind.sock`), then the requester is able to be authenticated, and you will be shown as the owner in the results of `rpcinfo`. `rpcinfo -d` will then work if called using the same user account that made the binding.